# repetición de items al hacer append a lista dentro de diccionario

Tags: python

Dado que este es un problema común cuando uno trabaja en python dejó un código ejemplo ( y mi visión sobre lo que ocurre). La situación es la siguiente:

- Se tiene un tipo de dato compuesto (lista) dentro de otro (diccionario)
- se desea agregar dinamicamente valores a las listas dentro del diccionario (por ejemplo dentro de un `for` definimos la clave, además del valor correspondiente a dicha clave)
- Como resultado del proceso vemos repetidos los elementos que deberían (según nuestra lógica) asignarse al correspondiente par clave/valor.

teniendo el siguiente listado:

```
enviroment = [(6,8,7),(12,2,3),(18,4,6)]
```

Si construimos la siguiente función (la lógica interna no es importante ; sin embargo a fin de entender, el objetivo de la función es tomar una lista  y asignar dentro de un diccionario de claves numéricas la cola de la lista , es decir todos los elementos menos el primero. El primer elemento construye la clave: `primerElemento % 3 + 1` ):

un primer intento puede ser:

```
def test(p_list):
    main = dict(zip(range(1,4),[[]]*3))   
    for elem in p_list:        
        main[elem[0]%3+1].append(elem[:2])
    return main
```

otro intento:

```
def test(p_list):
    main = dict(zip(range(1,4),[[]]*3))  
    for elem in p_list:  
        main[elem[0]%3+1] += list(elem[1:])
    return main
```

al ejecutarla pasandole como parámetro enviroment obtenemos

```
>>> test(enviroment)
>>>{1: [8, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6], 2: [8, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6], 3: [8, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6]}
```

Cuando lo que esperábamos es:

```
>>>{1: [8, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6], 2: [], 3: []}
```

¿Como podemos solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3):

La cuestión es que estamos asignando al elemento `diccionario[clave]` la referencia a la lista y no su valor. Al asignarle la referencia, cualquier modificación que hacemos a la lista se visualizara en los demás. Hay varías formas de sortear (workaround) este problema:

1. no modificar el item, sino, devolver su valor ya modificado:

   ```
   for elem in p_list:            
      main[elem[0]%3+1] = main[elem[0]%3+1] + list(elem[1:])
   ```
2. Tomarse el trabajo de definir cada uno de los elementos:

   ```
   def test(p_list):
       main = dict(zip(range(1,4),[[]]*3))
       main[1] = []
       main[2] = []
       main[3] = []
       for elem in p_list:
           main[elem[0]%3+1].append(elem[:2])
       return main
   ```

Seguramente esta segunda opción es la menos recomendable. Probablemente existan más pero las desconozco. El hecho es que este problema es común, mas cuando empezamos a trabajar mas aplicando el paradigma funcional que la orientación a objetos. En sintesís, se repiten los elementos porque en realidad pasamos una referencia... lo que modificamos es el objeto referenciado y **no** el valor dentro del diccionario para dicha clave.